# How to find out which images are indexed by Google

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-image-search

I just tried to make request like `site:example.com` in `Images` section of Google search. There were about let's say 100 images found (no "Show more results" or any similar was available in the bottom). But I know that there are much more images on the site.

Can I state that if an image is not shown by Google image search for my domain - this image in not indexed by Google?

Comment: Are the images served from the same domain as your pages where those images are embedded?

Comment: You can try submit a image sitemap to google, make sure all image file name are appropriate and include alt.

Comment: @Amit, the answer is yes. All images hosted on the same domain.

Comment: @Peter, I did this thing if I understand your point correctly. I created a sitemap (many sitemaps with one sitemap index to be more precise). I create a sitemaps and submitted it to Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: make sure your sitemap syntax as in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

Comment: Yes, @Peter! I created sitemaps in accordint to the document you specified.

Comment: @RomanMatveev did you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Google image search and type "site:yourdomain.com" into the search field. Google should list all images indexed for this domain.

Comment: But I just described the same thing in the OT... The problem is that Google images can display only 169 images for my site, but GWT indicated that there are 1198 images indexed...